# Identificar as posições dos objetos

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho duas imagens que movo, e que guardo a sua posição x e y num array. Crio um clone de cada imagem, e ao parrar de mover (onmouseup) guardo a sua posição. Dou o mesmo id a cada imagem gerada para poder saber qual. Sem criar dois arrays, queria saber como depois identificar no array, qual é a posição do objeto.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/9/

Comment: Já estás a guardar o ID no `ddData.movidos`, podes usar essa ID para recuperar os dados de novo certo? Como queres recuperar os dados ou indentificar o objeto?

Comment: Como posso identificar, porque quando imprimo o array, não sei qual é o elemento que foi movido. Ou seja qual a imagem, so sei o seu id.

Comment: Se sabes o ID podes fazer `document.getElementById(id);` certo? também podes guardar no objeto `ddData.movidos` um campo com `el: ddData.element`.

Comment: Sim sei o id, mas quando crio o clone meto que se for a imagem 1, os varios clones dessa imagem são todos '1', se for a imagem 2, todos os clones dessa imagem são 2. Assim consigo saber qual é a imagem. No array tenho todas as posiçoes, mas nao sei a qual imagem pertence, por exemplo se é o clone da imagem 1 ou 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro um ajuste na função onde crias os clones. Algo assim:

```
function mousedown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var el = ddData.element = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var id = ddData.element.id
    if (!el || el.tagName == 'svg' || ddData.movidos[id]) return ddData.element = null;
    var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
    el.id = id + '_' + (ddData.contadorElementos++);
    el.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
```

Desta maneira cada novo clone vai ter o ID original, e o elemento que arrastas (`ddData.element`) vai ter um ID único formado pelo ID do elemento original (`img1` ou `img2` no exemplo que deste) mais uma parte `_x` que é o numero do `ddData.contadorElementos` que vai sempre aumentando a cada elemento gerado.

Dessa maneira tens sempre IDs unicas e podes ir buscar o elemento quando precisares e cuja ID está registada nas chaves do teu objeto `ddData.movidos`.

Comment: para o mesmo projeto, queria parar de mover e de fazer o clone a um certo valor. Por exemplo quando criar no maximo 10 clones.